# e2313 constant expression required

Tags: c++, c++builder, visual-c++

Есть структура:

```
struct my_rectan
{
  unsigned int x, y;
};


 unsigned int coutLines = file->Count;
  const a = 100;
  my_rectan rectan[a];
```

Пробую писать *my_rectan rectan[coutLines];*, но выбивает ошибку - **e2313 constant expression required**. Как правильно записать?

Comment: `my_rectan rectan[100];` попробуйте

Comment: Я то пробовал. Но мне нужно, чтобы число менялось, при запуске программы (проверке файла). Типа, как динамический массив. Но я не понимаю как его записать в этом случае.

 `unsigned int coutLines = file->Count;
  my_rectan rectan[coutLines];   <<== Вот так.`

Comment: Если вам нужно такое - так и напишите. new[] попробуйте еще.

Comment: Что-то пробую-пробую...Не пойму как, извините. Как это сделать именно в моём примере? Что бы размерность массива задавалась с какой-то переменной, а не константы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавайте массив через `new []` с указанием размера:

```
my_rectan* rectan = new my_rectan[coutLines];
```

После использования осовбождайте через

```
delete [] rectan;
```

Answer (score 0):

В С++ нельзя объявить массив переменной длины на стеке, т.е. нельзя написать `int a[n]`, где `n` - это не константное выражение. (Компилятор G++ позволяет это сделать, но это расширение языка).

По этому массив надо выделять "в хипе". Рекомендуемый способ - это использовать `std::vector<T>`, например

```
std::vector<my_rectan> rectan(countLines);
```

Вектор обычно реализуется как структура с тремя указателями, так что накладные расходы очень малы.

Если же хочется совсем уменьшить накладные расходы, то можно использовать `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<my_rectan[]> rectan(new my_rectan[countLines]);
или
auto rectan = std::make_unique<my_rectan[]>(countLines);
```

`unique_ptr` хранит только один указатель, по этому накладные расходы будут равны нулю.

Использование сырых указателей (т.е. `T*`) и ручной вызов `delete[]` не рекомендуется, т.к. для этого есть безопасные обертки в стандартной библиотеке.